# Karate match each on response assertion is failing to identify missing keys in response

Tags: karate

I have a match each assertion like below in my code. Just tried creating similar examples as my code, just to explain the issue.

```
  Scenario: Example scenario 1

    * def response =
"""
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        password: "abc123"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "David",
        password: "abc123"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Mike",
        password: "abc123"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Johny"
    }
]
"""

    * match each response[*].password contains 'abc123'
```

**Test status : Pass**

Password field is missing in object 4(where id=4). Above test is passing for me. I am expecting Karate to fail the test in this case. How can I make my test fail in this case?

```
  Scenario: Example scenario 2

    * def response =
"""
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "David",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Mike",
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Johny"
    }
]
"""

    * match each response[*].password contains 'abc123'
```

**Test status : Pass**

Here, there is no password field at all in response. But my test is passing.

Need a work around to fail these kind of scenarios.

Example 3 :

```
    * def response =
"""
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        password: "abc123",
        skills :[ "training", "management"
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "David",
        password: "abc123",
        skills :[ "training", "management"
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "David",
        password: "abc123",
        skills :[ "training", "coding"
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "David",
        password: "abc123",
        skills :[ "training", "management"
        ]
    }
]
"""
```

Considering `* match each response contains { password: 'abc123' }` format(mentioned by @peter) to check example 1 and 2, what if I want to check skills array having 'training' in each object under response? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `response[*].password` is a JsonPath expression that will return an array of all the `password` key-values found and will return only 3 in your case.

What you are looking for is this:

```
* match each response contains { password: 'abc123' }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree with your point. Updated the question with example 3. Please help me understand how can I achieve that case using your format of match each. thanks!

Comment: Sure, accepted the answer and created a new question( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880547/using-match-each-contains-for-json-array-items-assertion)

Answer (score 2):

you can use match each to validate the json schema
https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-each

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, looking at the schema part now.  I will accept the answer once I am done with schema part. Just need a clarification. Is karate not supposed to fail the test in this case? Looks like a possible karate bug to me.