# Using match each contains for json array items assertion

Tags: karate

I would like to add an assertion on skills array containing 'training' in each of the items under response array. how can I do this using match each format `* match each response contains { password: 'abc123' }`(without using JsonPath expression). I'm expecting my test to be failed for below example since skills array is missing in fourth object.

```
Scenario: Test scenario

* def response =
"""
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        password: "abc123",
        skills :[ "training", "management"
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "David",
        password: "abc123",
        skills :[ "training", "management"
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "David",
        password: "abc123",
        skills :[ "training", "coding"
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "David",
        password: "abc123"
    }
]
"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def expectedSkills = ['training']
* match each response contains { skills: '#(^expectedSkills)' }
```

You know, you should really read the documentation. It will save you a LOT of time :) https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation

Comment: yes, it's working now. I was using match each with JsonPath expression. But encountered a scenario where json array used in assertion was missing in response and karate was passing the scenario. So failed to get the perspective in this case, even after knowing stuff. Anyway, thanks for the your response. You guys have a great documentation.